# Principal ideals as generated groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This seems like a pretty simplistic question, but I can't find a solid, non-ambiguous answer to it. The question I'm given:

Is $I$ a principal ideal of $R$? Given:
$R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=\left\langle 6,10\right\rangle_{R}$

$I$ is clearly an ideal, however for it to be principal, there must be a $a \epsilon R$ such that $I=\left\langle a\right\rangle = \left\{ ra|r,a\epsilon R\right\}$

Now, since any element of the ideal has the form $6r+10s$ where $r,s \epsilon R$ clearly the ideal could be generated by {2}, since all the elements in the ideal will be even.

My question: is the ideal principal if it contains *all* elements generated by $a$? Or do all elements of a principal ideal need to be able to be generated by a single element - in which case the ideal would form a subset of the generated group. In our example, all elements of the ideal area generated by $2$, but not all elements generated by $2$ are in the ideal. Most sources that I've found don't particularly specify, as they seem to assume something that I'm missing (apparently).

Thanks!

Comment: Ideals are *principal*. Principles are quite a different thing!

Comment: Edited :P I wasn't paying much attention to spelling, as I'm more concerned with the definition. With this one point cleared up I should be able to do the assignment with no problems.

Comment: Why do you think that not all elements generated by 2 are in the ideal <6,10>?  After all, 2*6-10 = 2 itself is in the ideal.

Comment: That's a fair point, I hadn't actually thought of that. However just to eliminate the need to prove that *all* elements generated by 2 are in the ideal, what is the precise requirement for a principal idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, there *is* equality: $\langle 6, 10 \rangle = \langle 2 \rangle$.  Using the Euclidean algorithm, we know we can find $s, r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $6r + 10s = 2$.  From here, you can just multiply the entire thing through by any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$:

$$6xr + 10xs = 2x$$

By definition, for any (two-sided) principal ideal:

$$\langle x_1, x_2, ...,  x_n \rangle = \langle y \rangle = \{r \cdot y:r \in R\} = \{y \cdot r:r \in R\}$$

for some $y \in R$.  In other words, this will indeed be **all** elements generated by $y$.

---

Side note: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a [principal ideal domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain) - i.e. all ideals are principal.  A useful fact is that any ring endowed with some form of the Euclidean algorithm as a means of finding GCD's and applying [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) will be a principal ideal domain.

Comment: That does actually make alot of sense! I had previously thought something along those lines. Does that imply that if the ideal representative *cannot* be written in the form of the group generator, then the ideal is *not* principal?

Comment: I edited my response to include some more detail.  Certainly, as in $\mathbb{Z}$, if you can use the Euclidean algorithm to rewrite any multiple of elements as a single element.  However, not all principal ideal domains (PID's) are so-called Euclidean domains.  I.e. you can have a principal ideal domain that is not a Euclidean domain, and to be honest, I'm not really sure how things would work as far as rewriting an ideal generated by multiple elements as a principal ideal.  After a bit of searching, I did find one such example though: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~raw/MTH5100/PIDnotED.pdf

Comment: I feel like I should add that all fields are principal ideal domains as well.

Comment: I think that'll do for now... it's definitely given me a bit more context! Thanks.

Comment: Well, I did my best.  The simplest answer to your question is that the ideal will be all the elements generated by $a$.  I do recommend Wikipedia though for some of the follow-up.  Compared to most other math topics, it's rather accessible when it comes to algebra.